From whom did Eve learn eating the forbidden tree was a sin!
Was it from Adam or God that Eve learned of the commandment to not eat of the fruit of the forbidden tree?
Eve is quoted in Genesis replying to the devil and she creates this understanding that she was present when God gave Adam that command.
Genesis 3:3

We may eat of the fruit of the trees in the garden, but God said, ‘You shall not eat of the fruit of the tree that is in the midst of the garden, neither shall you touch it, lest you die.’”


Gen 2:16 provides the answer

Scripture doesn’t specify who Eve learned the command from. God walked with both of them in the garden, so there’s no reason to think God wouldn’t discuss this with her; being the one rule he had for them. Then again, he very well could have entrusted this task to Adam and simply confirmed this rule if Eve ever asked. It’s all speculation.
The thing the narrative makes clear, however, is that she did know the command and the stated consequences regardless of who she heard the command from. The serpent only challenged her as far as the consequences of eating the apple goes - the serpent did not challenge the notion that God had commanded her not to touch the tree nor to eat its fruit.
So even if she was deceived in terms of the consequences- she was not deceived in terms of what God had commanded. Hence their sudden realization that they were “naked” - aka, they experienced guilt and didn’t want to come into God’s presence. So God himself provided coverings for them (to atone = to cover) so that they could stand before him once more.

Why doea scripture say sin entered into the world through Adam and not Eve?

Sounds like Eve learned about this commandment from Adam and not directly from God according to the verse below
Genesis 2:15-18

The LORD God took the man and put him in the garden of Eden to work it and keep it. And the LORD God commanded the man, saying, “You may surely eat of every tree of the garden, but of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil you shall not eat, for in the day that you eat of it you shall surely die.” Then the LORD God said, “It is not good that the man should be alone; I will make him a helper fit for him.”

God gave that commandment to Adam before He created Eve so the most logical conclusion is that she learnt of the commandment from Adam and that explains why she doubted and fell for the lie from the devil, but is it possible that God could have given the command a second time to them while they were together? This explains why new testament books say the man sinned and not the woman because the commandment was given to Adam who was supposed to be responsible over his own wife to prevent her from sinning.
But Adam wouldn't control every single action Eve made so he wasn't responsible for her fall, he was responsible for his own fall by loving his wife more than he feared God.
